# How to change the PHP path in linux xampp?

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

I'm running on Ubuntu, and I've installed PHP using `sudo apt-get install php` by command line.

---

The following is the route I want to point PHP to:

```
/etc/php/7.0
```

What files of xampp do need changing to point to /etc/php/7.0?

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you need xampp on Ubuntu? When all the necessary tools to start a server is built right into Ubuntu/Linux. you can even install phpmyadmin using `apt install phpmyadmin`

Comment: My main system is Linux, I have many development tools, I use docker containers a lot. I need to change the path because I need the sql server driver which does not come in xampp. If I install apache globally or another server I will have problems in the system.
The performance of the computer is something important for me.
That's why I use containers and xampp.